# Remove all other div's on click of a image

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label>Project Type </label>
    <div>
    <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control ">
        <option value="">Select Project Type</option>
        <option value="Independent_House">Independent House</option>
        <option value="Duplex_House">Duplex House</option>
        <option value="Pent_House">Pent House</option>
    </select>
    </div>

<div  class="cato" id="category_Independent_House" style="display:none">    
  <input type="button" id="addindependant" value="Add Property" />          
    <div id="cato_Independent_House">
      <div class="form-group">                  
        <label>Bed Rooms</label><label>Bath Rooms</label> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div  class="cato" id="category_Duplex_House" style="display:none">
  <input type="button" id="addduplex" value="Add Property" />   
    <div id="cato_Duplex_House">
      <div class="form-group">                  
        <label >Bed Rooms</label><label>Bath Rooms</label>
      </div>                        
    </div>
  </div>
  <div  class="cato" id="category_Pent_House" style="display:none">
  <input type="button" id="addpenthouse value="Add Property" />
    <div id="cato_Pent_House">
      <div class="form-group">                  
        <label >Bed Rooms</label><label>Bath Rooms</label>
       </div>
    </div>
        </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
  js(function() {
   js('#addindependant').click(function(e){
   js('#cato_Independent_House').append('<div class="form-group submenu">
              <div ><select name="rooms[]" >
                    <option value="1">1BHK</option>
                    <option value="2">2BHK</option>
                    <option value="3">3BHK</option> 
                    </select>
               </div>
               <div><select name="toilets[]">
                    <option value="1">1T</option>
                    <option value="2">2T</option>
                    <option value="3">3T</option>
                    </select>
               </div> 
               </div>');
          });
  js('#addduplex').click(function(e){
   js('#cato_Duplex_House').append('<div class="form-group submenu">
              <div ><select name="rooms[]" >
                    <option value="1">1BHK</option>
                    <option value="2">2BHK</option>
                    <option value="3">3BHK</option> 
                    </select>
               </div>
               <div><select name="toilets[]">
                    <option value="1">1T</option>
                    <option value="2">2T</option>
                    <option value="3">3T</option>
                    </select>
               </div> 
               </div>');
       });
   js('#addpenthouse').click(function(e){
    js('#category_Pent_House').append('<div class="form-group submenu">
              <div ><select name="rooms[]" >
                    <option value="1">1BHK</option>
                    <option value="2">2BHK</option>
                    <option value="3">3BHK</option> 
                    </select>
               </div>
               <div><select name="toilets[]">
                    <option value="1">1T</option>
                    <option value="2">2T</option>
                    <option value="3">3T</option>
                    </select>
               </div> 
               </div>');
          });
     });
      js(document).ready(function(){    
        js('#category').change(function () {
           var selection = js(this).val();
           js('#category_'+selection).show('slow');
             });
         });
     </script>
```

This is my code. When I select the category based upon the category selected the divs `cato_Independent_House` `cato_Duplex_House` and `category_Pent_House` get appended to their respective categories.

Consider first `independant house` is selected from drop down so its respective `cato_Independent_House` gets appended to the div with id `id="category_Independent_House"` on click of the button.after that when `duplex house` is selected from drop down its respective 'cato_Duplex_House' gets appended to div with `id="cato_Duplex_House"` on click of the button.

But when I go back and select Independant house it must not show previous selected div until the button is clicked. But here the div is already been displayed even the button is not clicked when I go back.The previous menu should show its div only when the button is clicked.i.e, the previous divs must get empty or removed when other option is selected.How to do this?

Comment: Post your current javascript code.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
     js(document).ready(function(){ 
        js('#category').change(function () {
           var selection = js(this).val();
           js('#category_'+selection).show('slow');
             });
        </script>

Comment: Why do you have mixed html and javascript code before your <script> tag? Is this your real code ? If it is - the js code should be in <script> tag (or loaded from a .js file ).
This is very confusing

Comment: I have edited and corrected the code

Answer (score 0):

**js**

```
js(document).ready(function(){ 
        js('#category').change(function () {
           var selection = js(this).val();
            js('.cato').each(function() {
                console.log(js('.cato'));
                if(js(this).attr('data-visible') != "true") {
                    js(this).hide();
                }
            });
           js('#category_'+selection).show('slow');
             });
         js('.addProperty').click(function(){
             js(this).parents('.cato').attr('data-visible','true');
         });
         });
```

**html**

```
<input type="button" id="addduplex" value="Add Property"  class="addProperty" />
```

add class addProperty to all your add property input

Working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BCe56/) Link. I guess this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You should use the jquery `hide` method to hide the others divs depending on wich one you have selected:

```
js(document).ready(function(){ 
    js('#category').change(function () { 
      var selection = js(this).val(); 
      js('#category_'+selection).show('slow'); 
      if(selection=="Independent_House"){
          js('#cato_Duplex_House').hide();
          js('#cato_Pent_House').hide();
      }else if(...){
          {otherCases}
    });});
```

And if you want to clear also the inputs selection of each div you could do something like this:

```
js("#input_controller_id_to_clear")[0].selectedIndex = -1;
```